# How do I group all my groups into one 'master' group?

Tags: groups, outliner

I am currently making a medieval cannon, and I have been naming all the parts of the cannon, also I grouped all parts into different groups for easier recognition. For example I grouped all components of the wheel together as one group (e.g. Rim, Disc etc.) But how can I 'group all groups' together as the final product in order to publish my model. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more? What's the purpose of having everything grouped? I think you may want to use parents instead of groups for some objects. even shapekeys could be a way of cleaning and organizing your file, if your canon is mostly static I assume. Really depends on what you're going for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects can belong to more than one Group. You can simply select all objects you need and group them into a MASTER_Cannon group that can be used for appending/linking.